# Somar valor de um array

Tags: php, array, pdo

Estou precisando fazer a soma de valores providos de um array. O array vem de uma select no banco de dados.

O array está desta forma:

```
Array ( 
         [0] => Array ( [valorPagamento] => 12 ) 
         [1] => Array ( [valorPagamento] => 50 ) 
         [2] => Array ( [valorPagamento] => 10 ) 
)
```

Gostaria de somar esses valores: 12,50,10

Já utilizei o `array_sum` desta forma:

```
echo "soma: ".array_sum($total);
```

A variável `$total`que trás o array, no entanto o resultado da sempre 0;

Também tentei essa função:

```
$sum = 0;
        foreach($total as $key=>$value){
            $sum+= $value;
        }
    echo $sum;
```

Aqui, quando eu uso a função `fetch`ele mostra apenas a primeira linha, quando uso  `fetchAll`ele mostra o seguinte erro:

> Unsupported operand types

Meus códigos são esses:
arquivo pagamentoContasDAO.php (apenas a função que eu to usando):

```
function soma(){
        try{
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT valorPagamento FROM pagamentocontas");

            $stmt->execute();

            $consulta = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $consulta;

        }catch (PDOException $ex){
            echo "ERRO 02: {$ex->getMessage()}";
        }
    }
```

arquivo soma.php:

```
<?php  
    require_once ("../DAO/pagamentoContasDAO.php");

    $dao =  new pagamentoContasDAO();
    $consulta = $dao->soma();


?>
```

arquivo pagamentoContas.php:

```
<?php

    require_once ("../Controller/soma.php");

    $sum = 0;
        foreach($consulta as $key=>$value){
            $sum+= $value;
        }
    echo $sum;

?>
```

Bom, espero que tenham entendido meu problema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você tem um array multidimensional, por isso `array_sum` não funciona. Sua função está quase correta, basta acrescentar a chave `valorPagamento`:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($total as $key => $value){
    $sum += $value['valorPagamento'];
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: Pode me agradecer dando upvote haha. É normal bater cabeça no início mesmo

Comment: Tá lá. Vlw mesmo.

Answer (score 5):

Usei muito esse metodo, hoje tem este:

```
 $total = array_sum ( array_column($itens, 'preco') );
```

Lembrando que a funçao array_column() apareceu no PHP 5.5